# How to get difference between rows and return new dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's assume that I have following dataframe:

```
Index.  0.  1.  2.  3.
  A.    10. 10. 10. 10.
  B.    20. 20. 20. 20.
  C.    30. 30. 30. 30.
  D.    40. 40. 40. 40.
  E.    50. 50  50. 50.
  F.    50. 50  50. 50.
  G.    50. 50  50. 50.
```

If I want to get difference between three rows, following dataframe must be generated:

```
Index.  0.  1.  2.  3.
  A.    10. 10. 10. 10.
  D.    30. 30. 30. 30.
  G.    10. 10  10. 10.
```

Currently, I couldn't find APIs for this behavior (`diff()` does not behave like this).

Are there any ways to achieve this?

Comment: How is this a difference? It just looks like you selected every 3rd row. Can you ensure the numeric values are correct?

Comment: @mozway I'm sorry, I correctly modified the result of new dataframe. The function is to substract between rows.

Comment: So you want D-A and G-D?

Comment: @Nohman Yes, the interval between indices is configurable. I think one of possible ways to achieve this is to do `diff()` and filter target rows. However, I'm suffering from filtering target rows.

Answer (score 1):

`diff(3)` will leave the first row null, which means you can just use `update` and then slice.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'1': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 50, 50],
 '2': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 50, 50],
 '3': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 50, 50],
 '4': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 50, 50]})

df.update(df.diff(3))
df = df.iloc[::3]
print(df)
```

Output

```
      1     2     3     4
0  10.0  10.0  10.0  10.0
3  30.0  30.0  30.0  30.0
6  10.0  10.0  10.0  10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can slice and use `diff`:

```
df2 = df.set_index('Index.').iloc[::3]
out = df2.diff().fillna(df2)
```

Less efficient alternative if you only want A/D/G, but interesting if you also want B/E, etc.:

```
df2 = df.set_index('Index.')
df3 = df2.diff(3).fillna(df2)
df3.iloc[::3] # here you can slice differently for other combinations
```

output:

```
          0.    1.    2.    3.
Index.                        
A.      10.0  10.0  10.0  10.0
D.      30.0  30.0  30.0  30.0
G.      10.0  10.0  10.0  10.0
```